# php jQuery form work until I added the ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make this form as simple as possible with a bit of jQuery validation and php validation using ajax. Everything was working fine until I tried to include the ajax.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script type="text/javascript">                                 
// we will add our javascript code here
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function() {
        var str = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contactfinal.php",
            data: str,
            success: function(msg) {
                if(msg == 'OK') {
                    result = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Your message was sent, we\'ll get back to you ASAP!</div>';
                    $("#fields").hide();
                } else {
                    result = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong></p>' + error + '</div>';
                }

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>  
  </head>
  <body>

      <div class="container">

    <h1>Get in touch!</h1>

      <div id="error"><? echo $error.$successMessage; ?></div>

     <form id="ajax-contact-form" action="">
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small class="text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" >
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleTextarea">What would you like to ask us?</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="content" name="content" rows="3"></textarea>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

        </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




  </body>
</html>
```

contactfinal.php

```
<?php

    $error = ""; $successMessage = "";

    if ($_POST) {

        if (!$_POST["email"]) {

            $error .= "An email address is required.<br>";

        }

        if (!$_POST["content"]) {

            $error .= "The content field is required.<br>";

        }

        if (!$_POST["subject"]) {

            $error .= "The subject is required.<br>";

        }

        if ($_POST['email'] && filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {

            $error .= "The email address is invalid.<br>";

        }

        if ($error != "") {

            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p>There were error(s) in your form:</p>' . $error . '</div>';

        } else {

            $emailTo = "me@mydomain.com";

            $subject = $_POST['subject'];

            $content = $_POST['content'];

            $headers = "From: ".$_POST['email'];

            if (mail($emailTo, $subject, $content, $headers)) {

                $successMessage = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Your message was sent, we\'ll get back to you ASAP!</div>';


            } else {

                $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><strong>Your message couldn\'t be sent - please try again later</div>';


            }

        }



    }

?>
```

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: I did try that now. The line that is throwing an error is : jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

If by jQuery library you mean including <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>, then yes. 

I am running it on MAMP and other examples have worked but I want to try do it myself and understand it better

Comment: Could you post AJAX request and response? (In Chrome F12 -> Network -> Headers and Response tabs)

Comment: What error is being thrown?

Comment: @keiv.fly, how do I do this on a mac? pressing F12 adjust my volume

Comment: Jay, error is (index):14 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: Code that is giving the error is: jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

Comment: Enable Web Inspector. Istructions here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html And then Command-Option-I

Comment: If jQuery is not defined then you haven't loaded jQuery properly.

Comment: I have resolved that issue by moving the code as mentioned below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to execute jQuery script before even loading the jQuery library. Try to move the whole jQuery `jQuery(document).ready()` snippet right after loading the `bootstrap.min.js` file and everything would work fine.

Not sure if you are there yet, but the PHP part doesn't return any response. You should use `echo $successMessage` and `echo $error` if you want to be able to append the error/success messages from the AJAX response.

You should either `echo` the response as it is, or more advanced, you can `json_encode` it in array -

```
<?php

    $error = ""; $successMessage = "";

    if ($_POST) {

        if (!$_POST["email"]) {

            $error .= "An email address is required.<br>";

        }

        if (!$_POST["content"]) {

            $error .= "The content field is required.<br>";

        }

        if (!$_POST["subject"]) {

            $error .= "The subject is required.<br>";

        }

        if ($_POST['email'] && filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {

            $error .= "The email address is invalid.<br>";

        }

        if ($error != "") {

            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p>There were error(s) in your form:</p>' . $error . '</div>';

            echo $error;

        } else {

            $emailTo = "me@mydomain.com";

            $subject = $_POST['subject'];

            $content = $_POST['content'];

            $headers = "From: ".$_POST['email'];

            if (mail($emailTo, $subject, $content, $headers)) {

                $successMessage = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Your message was sent, we\'ll get back to you ASAP!</div>';

                echo $successMessage;


            } else {

                $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><strong>Your message couldn\'t be sent - please try again later</div>';

                echo $error;


            }

        }



    }

?>
```

Next, since the server is returning the message, you can just append the response in the error holder

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                 
// we will add our javascript code here
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function() {
        var str = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contactfinal.php",
            data: str,
            success: function(response) {

                $('#error').html(response);

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

This part `<div id="error"><? echo $error.$successMessage; ?></div>` is invalid, because you are trying to print `javascript` string into PHP. If you are following the AJAX snippet I above, you can simply replace that part with an empty div `<div id="error"></div>`

Comment: As mentioned above, I moved it and I get no errors now. I do have the echo code just under my <h1> tag :  <div id="error"><? echo $error.$successMessage; ?></div>

Comment: Have a look at my answer updated. I added extra details about the issues you are facing with. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Move this script before document.ready function

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Okay, great! This took away the error but the form does nothing. When I click submit it doesn't show the error message it should.

Comment: Check the response of ajax call, will it returns expected response.

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: alert(msg) inside the success of the ajax call and check what the response is generated.

Comment: Not sure if I put it in the right place..

'$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "contactfinal.php",
   data: str,
   success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
       // Message Sent? Show the 'Thank You' message and hide the form
       if(msg == 'OK') {
        result = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Your message was sent, we\'ll get back to you ASAP!</div>';
        $("#fields").hide();
       } else {
        result = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong></p>' + error + '</div>';
       }'